# Tagging separate files

Tags: taxonomy-terms, files, media

I wonder if, and how, the following would be possible to tag each uploaded file with one or more tags and show these files filtered on their tag(s).
I know it's possible to do this for nodes but have not found a way to tag single files.

The purpose of this would be the creation of an image bank in which the administrator can upload images or files (pdf, zip) and define each image/file as being, for example, 300dpi, print, high resolution, color, black & white, etc.

Comment: Hello Blix, and welcome on _Drupal Answers_. To which version of Drupal are you interested?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Ideally I would like to use Drupal 7. But Drupal 6 is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 files are not used independently. Most often, fields are used through a file field, on either a node (D6 or D&) or an entity (D7).

To do the above, I would suggest using a file field on something, that holds all the info about the file. You could add things like title, teaser  text, description in addition to tagging. For Drupal 6 the only option you have is to use nodes, for Drupal 7 you could use nodes or create your own entity in a custom module. The easiest thing will be to use nodes, as you wont need to create a lot of functions for editing, loading, rending... the entity. Nodes are probably also a good match in this case since the files are content on your site.

Another plus doing this, is that you would be able to use the Views module, and create different galleries or list of image files.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same. I guess we might have to add file field to entity type if own entity type is considered. Can you please explain how to use nodes to achieve this?